# Xcode - changing the indentation rules for switch statements

Tags: swift, xcode

When I write a Swift switch statement it indents the code like this:

```
switch foo {
case 1:
    // stuff happens
default:
    // other stuff happens
}
```

I want it to indent like this:

```
switch foo {
    case 1:
        // stuff happens
    default:
        // other stuff happens
}
```

Is there any way to do this?  All the questions I can find on the topic either point to plugins (which no longer work in the latest version of Xcode) or discuss which way is "correct" rather than offer a way to change it.

Comment: No, there's no way to do it. You have to live with it.

Comment: I *think* you could write an Xcode Code Snippet.

Comment: I think John's preference is much clearer. I wish Xcode would at least have an option to indent the case lines.

Comment: @AshleyMills not true, you can edit Xcode snippets (or create your own)

Comment: I tried out your suggestion only to find myself giving a classic Xcode-facepalm. It turns out that the default Xcode snippit for a switch case is perfectly correct, but its the editor changing the snippet when being applied. Just as when you paste a copied switch case. #facepalm!

Comment: This drives me batty.

Comment: You should definitely try AppCode. It has a lot of configurable indentation rules and much more.

Answer (score 21):

Xcode 11 now appears to have a preference for this (checked in beta 5):

- Go to `File > Preferences... > Text editing > Indentation`
- Check the `Swift` checkbox under `Indent switch/case labels in:`
- Party!

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to indent the `case` labels but doesn't further indent their contents, which if anything is even less readable than the other way. Hopefully they'll do something about that before the release version.

Comment: This does nothing for me at all. The Xcode developers should actually be ashamed of themselves for putting out such a bad piece of software.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to indent the switches - Tick the `Swift` checkbox in the `Indentation` section of `Text Editing`.

Note that if you use `SwiftLint`, having Switches that indent the `case` will throw a warning as it is generally accepted that the case will align with the switch. (Check box off)

[image: Switch Indentation]

Answer (score 2):

As of Xcode 9, there is an indentation settings page in Preferences/Text Editing/Indentation, but this includes no options for advanced indentation for each statement.

In Xcode 9, one may now re-indent code by marking it, pressing `Tab` or `Tab` + `Shift`

Answer (score 1):

**With Swift 3, Xcode 8.3.3**

The only way I know it is:

Select your code,

right click -> Structure -> Shift Left

right click -> Structure -> Shift Right

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is way to do this, you have to edit your snippets file, write extension for this or use the solution in above answers...

In fact you can hack it, create snippet for switchy (or something else related to switch, hit enter and your custom snippet should be applied)

http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/